# How to deal with with array and form (PHP and JQuery)?

Tags: php, jquery, forms, while-loop

I have a MySQL database table which has a unique ID identifier for each line:

```
id       text        cat
4        abc         1
233      bbb         2
45       efa         1
```

Using PHP, I show an HTML table where you can see the TEXT and CAT fields.
Each row of the table is shown using a "while" loop.
As you can see, I also store the IDs in the array `$val`.

```
    <?php
    ....
    $val = array();
    while($objResult = mysql_fetch_array($objQuery)){
    $val[] = $objResult["id"];
    ?>
    <table>
     <tr>
      <td><?php echo $objResult["text"];?></td>
      <td><?php echo '<a href="#" id="open">'.$objResult["cat"].'</a>';</td>
     <tr>
     <?php
      }
     ?>
    </table>
```

Now comes **the tricky part**.
Using JQuery, I would like to be able to click on the CAT cells in the html table and open a dialog window where I can change the value of CAT.
Here is the form:

```
<form action="modcat.php" method="POST" id="modcat">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <select id="cat">
                    <option value="a">a</option>
                    <option value="b">b</option>
                    <option value="c">c</option>
                </select>
                <input type="hidden" name="val" value="<?php
                for ($i = 0; $i < 1000; $i++) {
                    echo $val[$i];
                }
                ?>">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("a#open").click(function () {
            $('#finestra').dialog("open");
            return false;
        });
        $('#finestra').dialog({
            modal: true,
            autoOpen: false,
            buttons: [{
                    text: "modifica",
                    click: function () {
                        submitform();
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                }, {
                    text: "annulla",
                    click: function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                }]
        });
        function submitform() {
            $('#modcat').submit();
        }
    });
</script>
```

As you can see, I am trying to send to the form the corresponding value of ID (through a hidden input).
As it turns out, I put together all the IDs of all the table in the array `$val`.
How can I send to the form just the one which is chosen?

Comment: ***Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).*** [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: You should not use same `id` multiple times in a single DOM. Use class instead. Because if you define `id` with same value more than 1 time then jquery will consider very 1st `id` from top in the DOM.

Comment: I know my syntax is not up-to-date. I will look into PDO. Thanks.

Comment: Himanshu, can you give me an example please?

Comment: You haven't even attempted to construct the code to manipulate the values in the database... Look into JS AJAX to read/write to MySQL database. Oh, and if you use mysql_* then you 100% open to attack. It is **NOT** secure. Do not use it even to learn... At least use MySQLi_* over mysql.

Comment: Why all the downvotes on this, the question is fairly well defined, and not about handling the submitted form (hence no need to include that code in the question).

Comment: Steve, thanks. I have omitted the two "notorious" lines now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the id to the html someplace, retrieve it in the click function, and add it to the form before submitting.

Here, i am adding the id as a data attribute, i also changed the id on the a element to a class, since your rendered html will contain multiple a elements, and ids should be unique

```
while($objResult = mysql_fetch_array($objQuery)):?>

   <table>
     <tr>
      <td><?= $objResult['text'];?></td>
      <td>
          <a href="#" class="open" data-id="<?=$objResult['id'];?>">
              <?=$objResult['cat'];?>
          </a>
      </td>
     <tr>
   </table>
<?php endwhile;
```

For the form, dont prepopulate the hidden field, just give it an id so its easy to target in js:

```
<form action="modcat.php" method="POST" id="modcat">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <select id="cat">
                    <option value="a">a</option>
                    <option value="b">b</option>
                    <option value="c">c</option>
                </select>
                <input type="hidden" name="val" id="hidden-id">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Then in your js update the value from the data attribute:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("a.open").click(function () {
        var clickedLink = $(this); //get clicked link
        var id = clickedLink.data('id'); //extract id from data attribute
        $('#hidden-id').val(id); //update hidden field value with id
        $('#finestra').dialog("open");
        return false;
    });
    ...
```

Comment: It works, with a minor change:   `<a href="#" class="open" data-id="'.$objResult["id"].'">'.$objResult["categoria"].'</a>`

Comment: Great, clad you got it working. Re the syntax, i prefer to only echo variables, not html, and prefer short echo tags `<?=` over `<?php echo` hence the change - your way i fine as well, its just preference